# Lightning email template with logo

Tags: lightning, email, email-template

I am trying to figure out how to add a logo to a Lightning template so that it will span the width of the email.  In Classic, I would create a letterhead & add an image of 550 width.  Can someone direct me on how to do this in Lightning?  We need this because the spacing on our current Classic templates is not looking right when sending via Lightning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with Salesforce technical support and was told that email templates need to be made in Classic still.